# how to secure whole pages except login page in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

I want to have whole site secured through login with FOSUserBundle. I tried to set security.yml like this

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /dashboard
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

But then I don't know what to set in config.yml
this is my config.yml

```
 imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }

framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:       ~
secret:          %secret%
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_proxies: ~
session:         ~
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            %kernel.debug%
strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
    # path:     %database_path%

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: %mailer_transport%
host:      %mailer_host%
username:  %mailer_user%
password:  %mailer_password%
spool:     { type: memory }
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
firewall_name: main
user_class: Dashboard\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

and this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace Proposals\ProposalsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Proposals\ProposalsBundle\Entity\Proposals;
use Proposals\ProposalsBundle\Form\ProposalsType;

/**
* Proposals controller.
*
*/
class ProposalsController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Proposals entities.
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('ProposalsProposalsBundle:Proposals')->findAll();

    return $this->render('ProposalsProposalsBundle:Proposals:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

When i open any page its not check either user is logged in or not.I want every page is secured through login if user logged in then every page open if user not logged in then page not show or redirect to login.any help appriciated

Comment: remove "anonymous: ~" from your security.yml. You'll also need to uncomment the last line (^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY)

Comment: i changed and then start the project but it not run

Comment: plz stop spamming...or does your life depend on a solution for this issue? ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Every time the same, nobody bats an eye on the documentation. Wayne. But for your spamming you shouldn't get a answer, but this would be unfair ^^

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            # other settings
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: when i login it moves

Comment: to http://localhost/QuickBacklog/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/be8c51 not move to http://localhost/QuickBacklog/web/app_dev.php/dashboard

Answer (score 2):

**for move to this URL**  localhost/QuickBacklog/web/app_dev.php/dashboard
you must add like this in the security.yml

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                provider:             fos_userbundle
                default_target_path:  /dashboard/                
            logout:     
                ........
                invalidate_session: false
            anonymous: ~
```

In the routing file

```
applicationlogin_success:
  pattern: /dashboard/
  defaults: { _controller: SampleBundle:Default:FrontPage }
```

BY USING **default_target_path : ROUTING_PATTERN** 
u will redirect it...