# Simple login form in Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

I've been looking for solution but couldn't find any answer which would fix my problem. I have the simpliest form login ( still learning symfony2 ) and I have no idea why it's not working.

My **security.yml**

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/profile
        provider: in_memory
        form_login:
            check_path: _security_check
            login_path: _portal_login

            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password

access_control:
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My **DefaultController** :

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{ 

 /**
 * @Route("/login", name="_portal_login")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{  
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(
            SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
        );
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }


    return array(
        'last_username' => $request->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error
    );

}

 /**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="security_check")
 */
public function securityCheckAction()
{
}

/**
 * @Route("/profile", name="profile_main")
 * @Template()
 */
public function profileAction()
{  
    return array();
}
}
```

and view of my **login form**

```
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("security_check") }}" method="post" id="login">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

<button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

As I said - as simple as it can be, and after clicking "login" I get **exception**:

```
The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?
```

**EDIT !!!!**

JUST FOUND A SOLUTION:
You need to edit security.yml so provider is in form_login section ^^

Answer (score 1):

try this code in your controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="_success_login")
 * @Template()
 */    
public function LoginAction() 
{
   //your code

   return $this->render('BundleName:Security:login.html.twig');
}
```

IN security.yml

```
 form_login:
        check_path: _security_check
        login_path: _success_login
```

Please look the page [click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394307/how-to-secure-whole-pages-except-login-page-in-symfony2/18545144#18545144)

Answer (score 0):

You have specified that only things that live under "/profile" should be firewalled. Change the pattern to:

```
secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/
    form_login:
        check_path: /login_check
        login_path: /login
```

That will require authentication and authorization for your entire app. Or

```
secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/Admin
    form_login:
        check_path: /login_check
        login_path: /login
```

That will require authentication and authorization only for routes that live under /Admin.

You didn't post your routing.yml file, but you will probably need to change your routing.yml file to this:

```
login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: SomeBundle:Authentication:logon }
login_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
logout:
    pattern:  /logout
```

Then I would rename your DefaultController to Authentication, since that is what its really doing.

Comment: ammm as far as I know it is enough to use "name" parameter in Routing section for given action and than I don't need to write it in routing.yml. Or am I wrong? Besides - I wanted only things under "/profile" to be firewalled. I just don't know how to link login_check with this form..

Answer (score 0):

Read how to use Template annotation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html). Or change your return statement to this:

```
return $this->render('bundle:controller:template', array(
        'last_username' => $request->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error
    ));
```

Read about Template Naming and Locations [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)

Comment: Every controller must return Response object, unless your app listens to view event - and that is the case when you use Template annotation. So either you return Response or use Template. BTW: do you import Template (use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template)?

Comment: I've edited my answer as I made mistake. $this->render() returns Response object (indirectly, so you dont need to use Response class)