# Symfony3 Login form : how to parametrize firewall in security.yml?

Tags: forms, security, authentication, config, symfony

My project is an interface entirely private and users have to sign in to enter. I try to build the login form. So, I don't need an /admin/ folder in my architecture.

I followed [Symfony instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html) to build a traditional login form.

When I try to get the home page (or another one), it redirects to the login form. At this point, everything is okay.

But my problem is that I have a redirect loop on my login page. When I try to sign in, it redirects every time on the login page instead of the page we trying to see.

**I think there is a problem in my security.yml file, to the level of firewall config.**

**security.yml**

First, I want to test my login form with a single and simple user but, at least, I will get users stored in a database. It's just for the test.

The secured area is my entire interface except the login page, that's why I did a login firewall (exactly as [Symfony recommends it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#be-sure-the-login-page-isn-t-secure-redirect-loop)).

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
               users:
                  mylogin:
                     password: mypwd
                     roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_firewall:
            pattern:   ^/login$
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            provider: in_memory
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login

                # csrf token options
                csrf_parameter:       _csrf_token
                csrf_token_id:        authenticate
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**Pages architecture :**

- /default/index.html.twig
- /security/login.html.twig

**routing.yml**

```
login:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Security:login }

logout:
    path: /logout
```

**SecurityController.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
   /**
   * @Route("/login", name="login")
   */
   public function loginAction(Request $request)
   {

      $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

      // get the login error if there is one
      $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

      // last username entered by the user
      $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

      return $this->render(
         'security/login.html.twig',
         array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
         )
      );
   }
}
```

Where I am wrong ? I don't understand why I have a redirect loop on my form.
Moreover, when I put fake login and password, Symfony doesn't show errors as it should do :

**login.html.twig**

```
{% if error %}
     <p class="bg-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

I need advices, please help me ;-)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works for me, thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394307/how-to-secure-whole-pages-except-login-page-in-symfony2/18545144#18545144).

Strangely, we have to put "anonymous: ~" inside the main firewall even if we want it private...

Now, when I try to access homepage, it redirects to my login form. When I sign in, the user is authenticated and it redirects to the homepage.

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:   ^/
            provider: in_memory
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login

                # csrf token options
                csrf_parameter:       _csrf_token
                csrf_token_id:        authenticate
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, with your solution I have an error when submitting the form : Invalid CSRF token. I really don't undestand what is the problem !!

Comment: Have you add the CSRF field in your login form ? You should read this : http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf_in_login_form.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Felurian your check_path must be behind your firewall.

For your Firewall you should change

```
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: false


          form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
```

and

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't solve the problem. Do I have to delete my "login_firewall" and put your code instead of my "secured_area" ?